# Multiple displays on Ubuntu 17.10 with nvidia cards

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have 4 nvidia graphics cards in my computer and I am trying to get multiple displays to function properly in Ubuntu 17.10.
All of them are now turning on and they are positioned properly.  I can move my mouse between all of them.  There are 6 monitors total.  I dual boot with Windows 10, and this configuration works fine on there.

The problem is that each screen is a separate xscreen.  Besides the main one, the others are a black screen with an X cursor.  Which means I cannot move my apps between the screens.   I am not sure if its twinview or mosaic mode that I need, or something else.  I like to be able to maximize windows depending on the screen it is on.  But I want them all to be connected and share the same desktop.

Most of the things I have tried results in either not being able to get to the login screen, or not being able to get past the login screen (it just loops).

I have:
3x Nvidia GeForce GT 610
1x Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070

I have the most recent nvidia drivers, but I also tried a few older ones.

I used nvidia-settings to make my xorg.conf.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 390.25  (buildd@lcy01-amd64-005)  Mon Jan 29 21:10:27 UTC 2018


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 1200
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1920 1200
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 3840 1200
    Screen      3  "Screen3" 1920 0
    Screen      4  "Screen4" 0 120
    Screen      5  "Screen5" 3840 120
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S32D850"
    HorizSync       27.0 - 90.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S32D850"
    HorizSync       27.0 - 90.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMS27A350H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer X263W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer G277HL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor5"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer G277HL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    Option         "TwinView" "true"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device5"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen5"
    Device         "Device5"
    Monitor        "Monitor5"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Anyone have any ideas? I have been trying to find information about this online, and keep getting conflicting opinions.  I tried xinerama, and it breaks everything and I cannot even login.  I tried mosaic mode, although its possible I did that wrong.  Thanks in advance to anyone that helps!!

If I figure it out before someone else, I will post the solution below :)